# TryGetValue() in Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to make a `TryGetValue`in my ASP.NET MVC3 Razor view, the code looks like this:

```
@var out;
@Model.Dic.TryGetValue(1, out);
<script type="text/javascript">alert(@out);</script>
```

I'm getting an error `CS0839: Missing Argument.` and i dont know why

**EDIT**
Now I changes it to:

```
@var myOut;
@Model.Dic.TryGetValue(1, out myOut);
<script type="text/javascript">alert(@myOut);</script>
```

Now I get: `"var" is not available in this context.`

Comment: `out` should have a variable name next to it. So `out @out` in your case as it is a reserved word.

Comment: oh yes I forgot the out, but now i'm getting a other error. I edited my question

Comment: You won't be able to use `var` as you are not assigning it anything that will allow the datatype to be inferred and it needs to be in a script block.

Comment: @{ TYPE myout = null;} try this.

Comment: However, even if u get it working, what you are doing is just wrong. you shouldnt be doing this stuff in the Views.

Comment: post the @{ TYPE myout = null;} as a answer, it worked. I know that its wrong to make this in the view but I have no other way. better dont ask why :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, based on understanding. I have not executed it.

```
@{
  var myOut;
  Model.Dic.TryGetValue(1, out myOut);
}
<script type="text/javascript">alert(@myOut);</script>
```